# ui component modifier

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, meta, enable-disable, modifier

I'm using Modifier class to disable some ui components on admin screen. But when I implemented modifyMeta() method, some of the needed ui components not included in the metadata array (eg: gallery)
So how can I modify these component? T4R.

```
public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
{
    $canEditApplication = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(AuthorizationInterface::class)->isAllowed('ScPortal_Backend::application_save');

    if (!$canEditApplication) {
        $meta['product-scheduler']['children']['ew_schedule_start_date']['arguments']['data']['config'] = [
            'disabled' => true
        ];
        $meta['product-scheduler']['children']['ew_schedule_end_date']['arguments']['data']['config'] = [
            'disabled' => true
        ];
        $meta['product-scheduler']['children']['ew_schedule_status']['arguments']['data']['config'] = [
            'disabled' => true
        ];

        $meta['gallery']['arguments']['data']['config'] = [
            'componentType' => 'container',
            'disabled' => true
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. hope it helps you.

```
//use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;
public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $attribute = 'your attribute code'; 

        $path = $this->arrayManager->findPath($attribute, $meta, null, 'children');
        $meta = $this->arrayManager->set(
            "{$path}/arguments/data/config/disabled",
            $meta,
            true
        );
        return $meta;
    }
```

Comment: thanks but the attribute on screen doesn't exist in the $meta array so i can't find it

Comment: which attribute you want to disable? if you want to disable gallery attribute just pass 'gallery' to $attribute variable. you can search attribute code to store->attributes->product